# Does the cubic planar graph with 6 3-faces and 6 7-faces have a name?

Tags: graph-theory

There is exactly one cubic planar graph with six 3-faces and six 7-faces (and no other faces). Surely it must have a name. What is it called?

Here is a picture of the graph embedded on the plane with a point at infinity:

[image]

[(source)](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~stolee/blogimg/plane37.png)

A slightly more general question: How can I find out what the names are of semi-famous graphs? A graph is semi-famous if it has an established name but is not easily found in a standard textbook on the subject.

I did try the [House of Graphs](http://hog.grinvin.org/) by searching using their drawing tool, but found nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Individual_graphs, and there are  more on MathWorld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/SimpleGraphs.html.  There is a page on Wikipedia with pictures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs

Unfortunately I don't have an answer to your question, but I would call it a "partially truncated cube", where the non-truncated vertices are opposite.  Accordingly, you could say that it is constructed from the truncated cube by performing a $\Delta$-$Y$ contraction on two maximally distant triangles.  I'm moving this comment to an answer in order to attach a picture of the truncated cube:

[image: truncated cube]

Comment: You beat me to "partially truncated cube" while I was off looking for a good wikipedia reference.

Answer (score 2):

[Sage](http://sagemath.org/) has search facilities for graphs with specified properties, and "knows" a large number of "named" graphs. As you work within a system running Python, you can do much more much easier, compared to what you get just by searching online databases using a www interface. The manual of the corresponding part is [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs.html).

Comment: I'm familiar with the Sage graph library, but not familiar with a functionality that allows me to give it a graph and ask for its name. The only thing I can think about is trying all graph.NAME objects and testing isomorphism (and some are parameterized).

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but you can do something like this:
 
    sage: import inspect
    sage: g=inspect.getmembers(graphs, predicate=inspect.isfunction)

will give you a correspondence between graph names and functions to create these named graphs (not all of entries of g would correspond to  actual named graphs, so you'd need to be a bit careful)